# Rolling Avg with time lag (in pandas)

Tags: pandas

I am trying to calculate a rolling average that starts 4 years before the date (For ex: with 1947, it would begin in 1943) and then takes the averages over the following 3 years. (So 1947 would be (1943 + 1944 + 1945)/3, so on and so forth...)

To do so I'd like to write a loop that:

Takes a list of years 
Subtracts 2 from each value
Takes the inc associated with that year
Subtract one, take the inc,
Subtract one, take the inc,
Average all three

Here's what I have so far:

d6 = d6.set_index('stateyear')

```
state_list = d6.index.values
years_list = d4.columns.values
values = []
stateyear = []
  for years in years_list:
    years -2, value
```

Sample Data:

```
Year  Amount
1943 123
1943  344
1943  234
1944  2423
1944  234
1944  576
1945  456
1945  456
1945  456
```

So it would need to first group by year. This is the code that accomplishes this in Stata in case it's a helpful reference:

```
gen avgstateinc = (Amount[_n-4] + Amount[_n-3] + Amount[_n-2]) / 3
```

Comment: Hi Slovakia, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please include a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @Gorlomi yes I've updated it and also included the code that I would use in Stata, as that is the background I have. Thank you!